# Return the ID of the last value inserted SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting data into members table, after I've inserted it I want to get the userID of the information just inserted. Whats the best way about doing this ?

My php code

```
    //Insert info into database
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (type, firstname, lastname, email, password, bio) VALUES ('$usertype', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$emailsighup', '$passwordsighnup', '$bio')";

        //Run a query to check if data has been inserted correctly.
        $records = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

I did try this SQL but was getting errors

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO members (type, firstname, lastname, email, password, bio) VALUES ('$usertype', '$firstname', '$lastname', '$emailsighup', '$passwordsighnup', '$bio')"; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(userID);
```

Comment: Have your try `mysqli_insert_id($connect); `

Comment: Brilliant thanks didn't realize it was that simple to do !

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `$connect` as the variable holding your connection information, which seems legit, you can get the value of the last id with:

`$user_id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);`

This is something you can do from the [PHP MySQLi interface](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php), rather than directly from SQL!

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a link to the stated interface manual reference  to your answer. I hope that's ok :-)

Comment: Perfectly fine! I forgot about linking it ;) thanks!